# Showing vectors are orthogonal

Tags: vectors

Let $u, v ∈ R^n$ be vectors.

Show that $u$ and $v$ are orthogonal if and only if $\Vert u + v\Vert = \Vert u − v \Vert$.

Can someone put an answer to this so I can compare it to my answer?

Comment: No, post your approach first ;)

Comment: Ill show you mine if you show me yours

Comment: I wrote it on paper, how do I post it?

Comment: The same way that you posted the question: type it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite straightforward:
Assuming both $u$ and $v$ are orthogonal:
$||u+v||^{2} = ||u||^{2} + ||v||^{2} \wedge ||u-v||^{2} = ||u||^{2} + ||v||^{2}$

So obviously $||u+v||^{2} = ||u-v||^{2} \Rightarrow ||u+v|| = ||u-v||$

Similarly in the other direction, you show that $u \cdot v = 0$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\left\| x-y \right\| =\left\| x+y \right\|$ iff $\left\| x-y \right\|^2 =\left\| x+y \right\|^2$ and $\left\| x-y \right\|^2 = (x-y) \cdot (x-y)$ with $\cdot$ the dot product.